# Baby Rudin, chapter 10, problem 1 - independence of order in multiple integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, integration

In problem 1, Rudin asks for a generalization of example 10.4, which states that if $f$ is continuous in the standard k-simplex $Q^k$, then the integral $\int_{Q^k} f$ exists, and that the order of the $n$ separate integrations is immaterial. He proves that by approximating $f$ by a sequence of functions which are continuous in a k-cell containing $Q^k$.

In problem 1 we need to show that the same hold, if $Q^k$ is replaced by any compact and convex $H \subseteq \mathbb R^k$. There's a hint, suggesting that one should approximate $f$ by continuous functions in $\mathbb R^k$ with support $\subseteq H$.

For fixed $\delta>0,$I've introduced the function $\varphi_\delta(t)
=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\delta}t & 0 \le t \le \delta \\
1 & t>\delta
\end{cases}$

and approximating $f$ by $F(x)=f(x) \varphi_\delta(\rho_{H^c}(x))$, where $\rho_E(x)=\inf \{ d(x,y) : y \in E\}$ is the distance between $x$ and $E$.

I can't follow his proof, Namely the inequality (7) on page 247 is problematic for me.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Lebesgue's theory is not allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inequality (7) is false for general $H$. And for a good reason. Recall that in Rudin's notation 
$$f_{k-1}(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1})=\int_{} f(x_1,\dots,x_k)\,dx_k$$
where I omit the limits of integration (they correspond to the size of some cube containing $H$). 
In Example 10.4 the function $f_{k-1}$ turned out to be continuous. But for general convex sets $H$ it 
is **not**. For example, consider some convex polygon in the plane: if one of its edges happens 
to be parallel to the axis $x_k$, and if $f\equiv 1$, the function $f_{k-1}$ will be discontinuous. 
Consequently, there is no hope to approximate it uniformly by $F_{k-1}$, which is what (7) was for.

We must set a more modest goal. As $\delta\to 0$, the functions $F$ converge to $f$ in the following sense:

1. $F$ converges to  $f$, monotonically, at every point except possibly the boundary of $H$.
2. $f$ is bounded above
3. Outside of $H$, $F$ agrees with $f$.
4. On every compact set $K$ contained in the interior of $H$, the convergence $F\to f$ is uniform.

**Lemma.** If $F$, $f$ and $H$ satisfy (1,2,3,4), then so do $F_{k-1}$, $f_{k-1}$ and $H_{k-1}$, where
$H_{k-1}$ is the orthogonal projection of $H$ along the $x_k$ axis.

Assume the lemma for now. Apply it  first to $F$, $f$ and $H$, then to $F_{k-1}$, $f_{k-1}$ and $H_{k-1}$, etc. 
Eventually we arrive at $H_1$ being a closed interval, $F_1$ converging to $f_1$ in the sense described above. 
It is an easy exercise in one-dimensional integration to prove that
$$\int F_1\to \int f_1$$
Now we are done, because the integrals $\int F_1$ do not depend on the numbering of coordinates (this
was proved early in Chapter 10).

It remains to prove the lemma, which is not super difficult but is quite boring... a good illustration of 
why people do not want to use Riemann integral in higher dimensions. It helps to draw pictures.

By a standard compactness argument, it suffices to prove that every point of the interior of $H_{n-1}$ has a
neighborhood on which convergence is uniform. Pick such a point 
$(a_1,\dots,a_{k-1})$. Consider the set $$T=\{t\in\mathbb R: (a_1,\dots,a_{k-1},t)\in H\}$$ which is a bounded interval.
Introduce the function
  $$d(t)=\operatorname{dist}((a_1,\dots,a_{k-1},t),\partial H)$$
Show that $d$ is concave (because $H$ is convex). We have $d(t_0)>0$ for some $t_0$. 
By concavity this implies a linear bound of the form 
$$d(t)>c \operatorname{dist}(t,\partial T)\tag{*}$$ where $\partial T$
is the boundary of the interval $T$. This gives you a version of (7): 
the length of the set $\{t \in T: d(t)<\delta\}$ is at most $c^{-1}\delta$. Moreover, since $d$ is uniformly (Lipschitz)
continuous, an
estimate  similar to (*) holds for segments parallel to $(a_1,\dots,a_{k-1},t)$ and near it. This gives a
uniform bound on $f_{k-1}-F_{k-1}$ in a neighborhood of $(a_1,\dots,a_{k-1})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm a little upset because the method of proof in example 10.4 doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: @MichaelTouitou There is some resemblance between (*) and (7). Inequality (7) is based on "transversality" of intersection between line segments and the boundary (they make nonzero angle). For general convex sets this intersection is not transverse everywhere, but it is transverse when we stay away from the boundary of the projection.

Comment: @user53153: I am confused by the first paragraph of your response. It appears that the k-simplex $ H $ defined by Rudin is a convex polygon with an edge parallel to $ x_k $, and yet Rudin proves that $ f_{k-1} $ is continuous.

Comment: It should be mentioned that User1337 is forgetting an assumption by Rudin that $ H $ has a nonempty interior.

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by user53153 and pasted my solution as follows, any comment is appreciate.

Since $H$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, there exists a $k$-cell $I^{k}$ with $a_{i} \leq x_{i} \leq b_{i}$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots,k$ such that $H \subset I^{k}$, and define
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{H} f = \int_{I^{k}} f = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}} f
\end{equation*}
Now the problem is that $f$ may not be continuous in $I^{k}$ (because $f$ may have nonzero value on $\partial H$), the existence of $\int_{I^{k}} f$ needs proof.

The uniformly convergence of $F_{k-1}$ to $f_{k-1}$ in Example 10.4
is not true in a general compact convex $H$. For example, consider some convex polygon in the plane: if one of its edges happens to be parallel to the axis $x_{k}$, and if $f\equiv 1$, the function $f_{k-1}$ will be discontinuous. Consequently, there is no hope to approximate it **uniformly** by $F_{k-1}$, which is what Example 10.4 was for.

We must modify the definition of multivariate Riemann integral by Rudin, we still define it by iterative integral, but the continuity of $f_{i}$, $i = 1,2,\ldots,k$ is replaced by the Riemann integratability of $f_{i}$, $i = 1,2,\ldots,k$, and the result is required to be irrelevant to its order of integration.

Put $f = f_{k}$, and define $f_{k-1}$ on $I^{k-1}$ by
\begin{equation*}
    f_{k-1}(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}) = \int_{a_{k}}^{b_{k}} f_{k}(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, x_{k}) d x_{k}
\end{equation*}
if $f_{k-1}$ is integratable iteratively, we can continue this process and after $k$ steps we arrive at a number $f_{0}$ and call it the integral of $f$ over $I^{k}$.

We must set a more modest goal. As $\delta \to 0$, the function $F$ converges to $f$ in the following sense:

1. $F$ converges to $f$ at every point except possibly the boundary of
   $H$.
2. $f$ is bounded above and continuous on $H^{\circ}$.
3. $F$ agrees with $f$ outside $H$.
4. $F$ is continuous on the whole space.
5. $H$ is compact convex set.

If $F$, $f$ and $H$ satisfy above conditions, then so do $F_{k-1}$, $f_{k-1}$ and $H_{k-1}$, where
\begin{equation*}
F_{k-1}(\mathbf{x}_{k-1}) = \int_{a_{k}}^{b_{k}} F(\mathbf{x}_{k-1},x_{k}) dx_{k} \qquad f_{k-1}(\mathbf{x}_{k-1}) = \int_{a_{k}}^{b_{k}} f(\mathbf{x}_{k-1},x_{k}) dx_{k}
\end{equation*}
and $H_{k-1}$ is the orthogonal projection of $H$ along the $x_{k}$ axis.

Note that $f_{k-1}$ is integratable because for the line $(x_{1},\ldots,x_{k-1},t)$, $a_{k} \leq t \leq b_{k}$, there exist only two points located at $\partial T$ defined below that make $f$ discontinuous and by Theorem 6.10, such a integral exists. And the order of the integrals $\int F_{1}$ is immaterial because the same statement in Example 10.4.

Now it suffices to prove that the conditions. Fix $\mathbf{x}_{k-1} = (x_{1},\ldots,x_{k-1})$. Consider the set
\begin{equation*}
T = \{t \in \mathbb{R}: (x_{1},\ldots,x_{k-1},t) \in H\}
\end{equation*}
which is a bounded interval.

Introduce the distance function
\begin{equation*}
   \rho_{\partial H}(t) = \operatorname{dist}((x_{1},\ldots,x_{k-1},t),\partial H)
\end{equation*}
Then $\rho$ is concave (because $H$ is convex) as follows,

Let $p \in H$, and $q$ be one of its closest points on $\partial H$. Since $H$ is convex, there exists a support hyperplane $h$ of $H$ which passes through $q$. Furthermore $h$ is orthogonal to the line $\overline{pq}$, since it supports the sphere $S_{p}$ centered at $p$ and passing through $q$. So $\rho_{\partial H}(p) = \rho_{H}(p)$. Clearly $\rho_{H}(p)$ is not bigger than $\rho_{h^{\prime}}(p)$ for any other support plane $h^{\prime}$ of $H$, because all these planes lie outside $S_{p}$. So $\rho_{\partial H}$ is the infimum of the distance functions to support hyperplanes of $H$. These functions are linear and therefore concave. So $\rho_{\partial H}$, as the minimum of a class of concave functions (linear is concave), is concave.

Because we have $\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0})>0$ for some fixed $t_{0}$ ($H^{\circ} \neq \emptyset$), by concavity, it implies a linear bound of the form
\begin{equation*}
\rho_{\partial H}(t) \geq c \operatorname{dist}(t,\partial T)
\end{equation*}
where $\partial T$ is the boundary of the interval $T$ and $c > 0$. This is because, by letting $\partial T = \{x_{k}^{1},x_{k}^{2}\}$ with $x_{k}^{1} < x_{k}^{2}$, the difference ratio is non-increasing (see Exercise 4.23), i.e.,
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t) - \rho_{\partial H}(x_{k}^{1})}{t - x_{k}^{1}} &\geq \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0}) - \rho_{\partial H}(x_{k}^{1})}{t_{0} - x_{k}^{1}} \quad \text{if }t \leq t_{0} \\
   \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t) - \rho_{\partial H}(x_{k}^{2})}{t - x_{k}^{2}} &\leq \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0}) - \rho_{\partial H}(x_{k}^{2})}{t_{0} - x_{k}^{2}} \quad \text{if }t > t_{0}
\end{align*}
which implies, since $\rho_{\partial H}(x_{k}^{1}) = \rho_{\partial H}(x_{k}^{2}) = 0$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t)}{t - x_{k}^{1}} &\geq \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0})}{t_{0} - x_{k}^{1}} \Longrightarrow \rho_{\partial H}(t) \geq \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0})}{t_{0} - x_{k}^{1}}(t - x_{k}^{1}) \geq \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0})}{t_{0} - x_{k}^{1}}\operatorname{dist}(t,\partial T)\\
\frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t)}{t - x_{k}^{2}} &\leq \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0})}{t_{0} - x_{k}^{2}} \Longrightarrow \rho_{\partial H}(t) \geq \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0})}{x_{k}^{2} - t_{0}}(x_{k}^{2}-t) \geq \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0})}{x_{k}^{2} - t_{0}}\operatorname{dist}(t,\partial T)\\
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation*}
c = \max \bigg\{\frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0})}{t_{0} - x_{k}^{1}}, \frac{\rho_{\partial H}(t_{0})}{x_{k}^{2} - t_{0}}\bigg\} > 0
\end{equation*}
Note that $c$ is a function of $\mathbf{x}_{k-1} = (x_{1},\ldots,x_{k-1})$.

Define
\begin{equation*}
\phi(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & t \geq \delta \\
\frac{t}{\delta} & 0 < t < \delta \\
0 & t = 1
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}
where $0<\delta<1$, and
\begin{equation*}
F(\mathbf{x}_{k}) = \phi(\rho_{\partial H}(\mathbf{x}_{k}))f(\mathbf{x}_{k}) \in \mathscr{C}(I^{k})
\end{equation*}
This gives us a version of Example 10.4: the length of the set $\{t \in T: \rho_{\partial H}(t) \leq \delta\}$ is at most $c^{-1}\delta$. Since $0 \leq \phi \leq 1$, it follows that
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ch10:exe1b}
|F_{k-1}(\mathbf{x}_{k-1}) - f_{k-1}(\mathbf{x}_{k-1})| \leq c^{-1}\delta \|f\|\tag{$\dagger$}
\end{equation}
As $\delta \to 0$, \eqref{eq:ch10:exe1b} exhibits $f_{k-1}$ as a **pointwise** limit of a sequence of continuous functions. Furthermore, we claim $f_{k-1}$ is continuous (not necessarily uniformly continuous) on $H_{k-1}^{\circ}$. Since for any $\mathbf{y_{k-1}}$ such that $|\mathbf{y_{k-1}} - \mathbf{x_{k-1}}| < \delta^{\prime}$,
\begin{align*}
|f_{k-1}(\mathbf{y_{k-1}}) - f_{k-1}(\mathbf{x_{k-1}})| &\leq |f_{k-1}(\mathbf{y_{k-1}}) - F_{k-1}(\mathbf{y_{k-1}})|\\
&+ |F_{k-1}(\mathbf{y_{k-1}}) - F_{k-1}(\mathbf{x_{k-1}})|\\
&+ |F_{k-1}(\mathbf{x_{k-1}}) - f_{k-1}(\mathbf{x_{k-1}})|
\end{align*}
Note that $F_{k}$ is continuous on $H$, thus is uniformly continuous on $H$, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
|F_{k-1}(\mathbf{y_{k-1}}) - F_{k-1}(\mathbf{x_{k-1}})| < \frac{\epsilon}{b_{k}-a_{k}}
\end{equation*}
for any $\epsilon>0$ if $\mathbf{y_{k-1}} - \mathbf{x_{k-1}} < \delta^{\prime\prime}$ for sufficiently small $\delta$. Hence $F_{k-1}$ is continuous. Thus, as $\delta^{\prime\prime},\delta^{\prime},\delta \to 0$, $|f_{k-1}(\mathbf{y_{k-1}}) - f_{k-1}(\mathbf{x_{k-1}})| \to 0$, $f_{k-1}$ is continuous at $\mathbf{x}_{k-1} \in H_{k-1}^{\circ}$, and the further integrations present no problem.